# Proof of the inequality of sums

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing

**N.B:** before downvoting this question without having finished reading it please leave a comment explaining why, so I can improve and ask better question in future, thanks.

In a problem I've to proof that
$$\sum_{x_i\in A}{x_i}=1$$
After some effort
I found the follow identity
$$\sum_{x_i\in A}{x_i}=\sum_{k=max(0,n-b)}^{min(a,n)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{n-k}}{\binom{b+a}{n}}}$$
Whit
$a\ge1, b\ge1, 1\le n\le a+b$

> I'd like to bound this sum between itself calculated for $n=1$ and $n=a+b$ in this way:
>
> $$\sum_{k=max(0,1-b)}^{min(a,1)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{1-k}}{\binom{b+a}{1}}}\le\sum_{k=max(0,n-b)}^{min(a,n)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{n-k}}{\binom{b+a}{n}}}\le\sum_{k=max(0,a+b-b)}^{min(a,a+b)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{a+b-k}}{\binom{b+a}{a+b}}}$$

**If this inequality is true** then

$$1\le\sum_{k=max(0,n-b)}^{min(a,n)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{n-k}}{\binom{b+a}{n}}}\le1$$
So
$$\sum_{k=max(0,n-b)}^{min(a,n)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{n-k}}{\binom{b+a}{n}}}=1$$

Because

$$\sum_{k=max(0,1-b)}^{min(a,1)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{1-k}}{\binom{b+a}{1}}}=\sum_{k=0}^{1}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{1-k}}{\binom{b+a}{1}}}={\frac{\binom{a}{0}\binom{b}{1}}{\binom{b+a}{1}}}+{\frac{\binom{a}{1}\binom{b}{0}}{\binom{b+a}{1}}}=\frac{a+b}{b+a}=1$$

and

$$\sum_{k=max(0,a+b-b)}^{min(a,a+b)}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{a+b-k}}{\binom{b+a}{a+b}}}=\sum_{k=a}^{a}{\frac{\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{a+b-k}}{\binom{b+a}{a+b}}}=\binom{a}{a}\binom{b}{a+b-a}=1$$

The problem is that i can't check this inequality my myself, can anyone explain me how to do it?

Comment: What is the set $A$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire The set $A$ is the image of a function $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a double counting argument. If we select $n$ objects from a set of $a+b$ objects there are $\binom{a+b}{n}$ ways to do this. On the other hand, if we pick $n$ objects from $a+b$ objects by selecting some $k$ objects from $a$ and the remainder from $b$, then if we sum over all possible values of $k$, we count the number of ways of selecting $n$ objects from $a+b$ objects. Thus
$$
\binom{a+b}{n}=\sum_{k=\max(0,n-b)}^{\min(a,n)} \binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{n-k}.
$$

Now divide both sides by $\binom{a+b}{n}$ and use the identity you have already proved to get your result.

Comment: I'm not experienced with double counting, is the $k=min(0,n-b)$ a typo?

Comment: Yes. I forgot the $k=$ in the lower bound of my summation. Double counting is simply counting the same collection of things in two different ways and observing that the two formulae you get must be equal since they count the same collection of things.